# Adding a button to a card with the RecyclerView pattern

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In accordance to [Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html), and the RecyclerView pattern, I have implemented an activity that shows cards for an array of items. I'd like each Card to have a button that pops a Dialog of options for that item:

[image]

as you can see there's a button to the upper right corner of each card. I have implemented this like so:

**CardViewHolder.java:**

```
public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView itemTitle;
    protected TextView itemCode;
    protected TextView itemDate;
    protected TextView itemStatus;
    protected Button optionsButton;
    public CardViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        itemTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        itemCode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemCode);
        itemStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemStatus);
        itemDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemDate);
        optionsButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.options_button);
    }
}
```

And then, Implemented my DataAdapter which is set in my activity for my RecyclerView:

**DataAdapter.java:**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewHolder>{
    private JSONArray mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;

    //constructor
    public DataAdapter(JSONArray myDataSet, Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        mDataSet = myDataSet;
    }
    //creates new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_text_view, parent, false);
        //set the view's size, margins, padding and layout parameters
        CardViewHolder vh = new CardViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //get element from dataset at position
        //replace the contets of the view with that element
        String title,itemCode,itemStatus, itemDate;
        title = itemCode = itemDate = itemStatus = "";
        try {
            JSONObject item = new JSONObject(mDataSet.get(position).toString());
            title = item.getString("desc");
            itemCode = item.getString("code");
            itemDate = item.getString("date");
            itemStatus = item.getString("status");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.itemTitle.setText(title);
        holder.itemCode.setText(itemCode);
        holder.itemDate.setText(itemDate);
        holder.itemStatus.setText(Html.fromHtml(itemStatus));
        holder.optionsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.length();
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }
}
```

My questions and thoughts about this are:

- how do i pass this button onClick listener the values of this item? trying to access `title` for example from within the onClick handler is an error because it's not a final variable and it's accessed from within an inner class. On the other hand, If i make my DataAdapter class implement View.onClickListener interface, I'm still unsure how do I get those item specific values from within onClick method.
- Is this considered a good practice at all? (Passing the application context to my DataAdapter)? Should i be attacking this from another angle maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily make your adapter implement `View.OnClickListener` or implement your own class that implements OnClickListener and has text param that you can set...

```
static class MyClick implements View.OnClickListener{

    String text
    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {

    }
} 

 MyClick click = new MyClick();
 click.text = text;
 holder.button.setOnClickListener(click);
```

Also why are you passing ApplicationContext and not activity context? the adapter is "bound" to the activity.

A better solution that enables you not to pass Context to the adapter is to use listeners, make your fragment / activity implement the listener and run the method onClick. for example:

@Adapter:

```
public interface MyAdapterListener {
    public void onCLick(String text);
}
 private MyAdapterListener mListener;
 ...

 void onClick(){
     mListener.onCLick(text)
 }
```

Comment: don't i need some kind of reference to the activity that implements the interface? `mListener.onClick(text);` throws a NullPointerException..

Comment: When instantiating the adapter assign the listener to the implementer, usually it's the activity or the fragment. Its a regular design pattern in android

Comment: Yes, but this is exactly my issue. If I use another Class to hold the text String, it does not have access to the activity listener. If I make the adapter itself implement View.OnClickListener I don't see how can I pass the string. :/

Comment: Of course it has, just pass the string in the callable

Comment: Yes, I meant the listener. I ended up passing the AdapterListener to the OptionsClick constructor. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No worries, if u need more help, let me know, now im of to sleep (: